# How to get user data from Office 365 API tools

Tags: api, office365, office365-apps

I'm using the Office 365 API tools, 
I want to get the logged-in user profile, e-mail, name,...

I want the user to log-in and then I can get his e-mail address.

How to do this?

I tried this:

```
 public static async Task<string> GetEmail()
    {
        var client = await EnsureClientCreated();

        var x = await client.Me.ExecuteAsync();


        return x.DisplayName;
    }


    public static async Task<ExchangeClient> EnsureClientCreated()
    {
        if (_discoveryContext == null)
        {
            _discoveryContext = await DiscoveryContext.CreateAsync();
        }

        var dcr = await _discoveryContext.DiscoverResourceAsync(ServiceResourceId);

        _lastLoggedInUser = dcr.UserId;

        return new ExchangeClient(ServiceEndpointUri, async () =>
        {
            return (await _discoveryContext.AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(ServiceResourceId, _discoveryContext.AppIdentity.ClientId, new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifier(dcr.UserId, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.UserIdentifierType.UniqueId))).AccessToken;
        });
    }
```

but this gets only the display name, I need the e-mail too.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Intellisense is your friend with the Class Libraries inside Visual STudio projects that get created in that sample file when you add the connected service.

```
string email = x.Mail;
```

will get you what you want.

Comment: There is no Mail property!

Answer (score 0):

Jeremy is correct that you'll want the Mail property. I'm not certain, but I don't recall whether the email address is surfaced in the ExchangeClient. Go back to the Connected Services windows and add the Users and Group API. That will give you what you need to get the user's email address.

```
Microsoft.Office365.ActiveDirectory.AadGraphClient aadClient = await ActiveDirectoryApiSample.EnsureClientCreated();
var currentUser = await(aadClient.Users
                .Where(i => i.ObjectId == "Logged in user's ID from ActiveDirectoryApiSample")
                .ExecuteSingleAsync());

string usermail = currentUser.Mail;
```